# Node.js and Mongoose - SEO Friendly URLs

Tags: node.js, seo, mongoose, friendly-url

I need to create SEO friendly URLs with Node.js, but before inserting document I'd like to check if there is already some other document which has url like that. I was searching for some module which could transform string to URL, but I found only one https://github.com/ludopoli/friendlyjs. Is there any other module which can do that and it has created interaction with Mongoose, so it checks for before created URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem myself quite recently, and your post made me feel like I should turn it into a module and publish it. I called it [monguurl](https://github.com/ahultgren/monguurl). Basically it hooks in before save, converts a specified field to a url-friendly string, checks if it's not taken already and if it is, appends a number.

Comment: @OsmanErdi in that case I'd be happy to receive an issue or a pull-request

Comment: can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165001/how-do-i-query-a-specific-post-by-slug-property-value-in-mongoose-instead-of-id

Answer (score 0):

You could ensure unique names on the database level. MongoDB has an [unique index type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-unique). This way no name (or whatever) could be used twice.